# How to log Excel and Word filenames open by me since 1 or 2 days?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, event-log

Currently, I have written VB.net program named `Extract-Working-Time` that read Windows SECURITY event.

This program work correctly and extract all actions I have done on my PC.

In event viewer LOG extraction, I can see that Excel or Word has been loaded but I don't find which files has been treated. I can only seen that Excel has been loaded.

```
2019-01-22 16:43:45;      4688;WW930     ;A424947   ;     13312;(13312)   ;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE;
```

Now, I will go a step further and search how to find the name of all Excel or Word files I have loaded in Excel or Word.

When I have the solution, I can then improve VB.Net program to include Excel and Word filenames in my report to document what I have done each working day.

Is there some logs of what is done in Excel and Word that I can use to create a report ?

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor file links in the %AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\ folder.

Comment: Yes this is a solution but I can not see when I have worked with some files because I have only the date of the last update.